# which option to choose in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#

Hope I don't get marked down for a dumb simple question...

I have written a couple of Windows Forms application before (very very basic!) and now my manager wants me to write an web front end application where I put a server into a text box and press enter and then it displays some settings about the server.

When I go into Visual Studio New Project which project should I choose to do this? This will be in C# and the options are below:

1. Windows Forms Application
2. WPF Application
3. Console Application
4. Class Library
5. WPF Browser Application
6. Empty Project
7. Windows Service
8. WPF Custom Control Library
9. WPF User Control Library
10. Windows Forms Control Library

What my aim is to write the code on the backend and then link a ASP.net webpage to the code so it reads information about settings on the server and displays all the stuff on the webpage.

Is ASP.net the best way to do this or something like WPF? Never done both so want to go for something that I can use again and again (and is simple to learn and implement!)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my manager wants me to write an web front end application
>
> When I go into Visual Studio New Project which project should I choose
>   to do this?

You want to click the **Web** tab under C# in the project template browser and choose the template for an  **ASP.NET Web Application**, or if you feel confident enough, you could even go for the MVC approach. This will largely depend on your skill level! You will need Visual Web Developer (2010 and prior), Visual Studio for Web (2012), or a version of Visual Studio that is NOT an Express Edition, and has web templates installed.

Just FYI...as for your list of project templates, this is why they are **NOT** suitable for web applications.

**Windows Forms Application**
Desktop application based on Windows Forms technology (WPF is the successor to WinForms)

**WPF Application**
Desktop application based on Windows Presentation Foundation technology

**Console Application**
MS-DOS style text based "console" application.

**Class Library**
Purely code which compiles to DLL and therefore cannot be directly executed.

**WPF Browser Application**
Similar to a "WPF Application" except that it is meant to run inside a browser.

**Empty Project**
Does what it says on the tin!

**Windows Service**
An application which runs in the background, limited/no user interaction.

**WPF Custom Control Library**
Allows custom WPF controls to be created, for use with a WPF application.

**WPF User Control Library**
Allows custom WPF user controls to be created, for use with a WPF application.

**Windows Forms Control Library**
Allows custom WinForms controls to be created, for use with a WinForms application.

Comment: fantastic - that is what I need to understand the options

Answer (score 2):

Don't select "Windows" in the treeview on the left if you want to create a web application. Select "Web" instead. There you have a whole bunch of ASP.NET application templates to choose from. I suggest you use "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application" or a classic "ASP.NET Web Application".

Answer (score 1):

WPF is Windows Desktop based. You need to select "Web Projects" on the left hand panel when creating a project. You want to use ASP .NET using either Web forms (easier to learn) or MVC (better for larger projects). Silverlight is like WPF for the web but probably overkill for what you are after.

A place to get you started: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/basics/hello-world/